# Rx Java - Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, rx-java2, android-viewmodel

I am pretty new to Rx Java and I have seen this question answered a number of times here on SO but the answers that are given don't seem to work for me.

So here is my stack trace:

```
2018-12-04 10:51:03.072 17083-17227/com.doolin.gary.mybooks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
Process: com.test.test.mybooks, PID: 17083
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:67)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableHide$HideDisposable.onNext(ObservableHide.java:67)
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:246)
    at io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject$BehaviorDisposable.test(BehaviorSubject.java:570)
    at io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject$BehaviorDisposable.emitNext(BehaviorSubject.java:565)
    at io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(BehaviorSubject.java:268)
    at com.test.test.mybooks.viewmodel.BookSearchViewModel$getBookList$1.accept(BookSearchViewModel.kt:35)
    at com.test.test.mybooks.viewmodel.BookSearchViewModel$getBookList$1.accept(BookSearchViewModel.kt:19)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.DisposableLambdaObserver.onSubscribe(DisposableLambdaObserver.java:42)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onSubscribe(BodyObservable.java:46)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnLifecycle.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnLifecycle.java:33)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:579)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7753)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
    at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:14096)
    at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:9992)
    at com.test.test.mybooks.view.search.SearchFragment$observeScreenState$1.accept(SearchFragment.kt:91)
    at com.test.test.mybooks.view.search.SearchFragment$observeScreenState$1.accept(SearchFragment.kt:28)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:63)
2018-12-04 10:51:03.072 17083-17227/com.test.test.mybooks E/AndroidRuntime:     ... 26 more
```

I have a list of books that I retrieve via my view model:

```
class BookSearchViewModel @Inject constructor(private val app: Application,
                                              private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
                                              @Named(RxModule.IO_THREAD) private val ioThread: Scheduler,
                                              @Named(RxModule.MAIN_THREAD) private val mainThread: Scheduler):
    AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private var disposables = CompositeDisposable()
    private val screenState = BehaviorSubject.create<ScreenState>()
    private val bookList = PublishSubject.create<List<BookSummary>>()

    fun observeBookList(): Observable<List<BookSummary>> = bookList.hide()
    fun observeScreenState(): Observable<ScreenState> = screenState.hide()

    fun getBookList() {
        disposables.add(bookRepository
            .fetchBookList()
            .doOnSubscribe { screenState.onNext(ScreenState.Loading("")) }
            .observeOn(mainThread)
            .subscribeOn(ioThread)
            .subscribe(this::handleBookListSuccess, this::handleBookListError))
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        disposables.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }

    private fun handleBookListSuccess(bookList: List<BookSummary>) {
        screenState.onNext(ScreenState.Success)
        this.bookList.onNext(bookList)
    }

    private fun handleBookListError(error: Throwable) {
       screenState.onNext(ScreenState.Error(getErrorMessage(error)))
    }

    private fun getErrorMessage(error: Throwable): String {
        return if (error.message.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            app.getString(R.string.book_list_error)
        } else {
            error.message!!
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly well I am observing in my fragment as follows:

```
   private fun addUIObservers() {
        disposables.add(viewModel.observeBookList()
            .subscribe {
                bookAdapter.loadBooks(it)
            })
    }

    private fun observeScreenState() {
        disposables.add (viewModel
            .observeScreenState()
            .subscribe { screenState ->
                when (screenState) {
                    is ScreenState.Success -> progress_layout.visibility = GONE
                    is ScreenState.Loading -> progress_layout.visibility = VISIBLE
                    is ScreenState.Error -> handleError(screenState)
                }
            })
    }
```

So when the user clicks on a book item I then open a book details activity and with via it's view model retrieve the book using the same pattern, using rx and observing in the activity.

When I hit back and return to the previous activity/fragment, if I pull to refresh, I get the above error.  This only occurs when returning back from the details activity.  As I said I'm very new to RX so please go easy on me but if anyone has any tips.  Please don't mark this as already answered as those answers don't work for me and I am observing and subscribing to and on the correct threads.

Comment: Change visibility of view on UI Thread in observeScreenState, that's the root cause

Comment: Please see that you can do all the work in a method that Activity class provides, that is "runOnUiThread(Runnable run)" Where you can have that code inside that run method of that Runnable run that you pass in. That ensures that the work is done in the Ui Thread, the actual thread that created the components.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to make modifications to a UI view outside the main thread and that it's not permitted in Android

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` after `.observeScreenState()` (import it first with `import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;`)

All UI logic must be executed on main thread. So if you have anything UI-related in `subscribe`, you have to add `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before it.

There can be one more case, specifically when you call UI logic in custom observables or use `RxBinding` framework which does that, then you need to add `.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`. This may be the case with your "pull to refresh" functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.  So I'm observing both the screen state and the book list from the fragment.  In relation to `AndroidScheduler.mainThread()` . I am injecting that via my `RxModule()` . If you wouldn't mind elaborating on your answer I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: The only thing that matters in this case is that all UI logic must be executed on main thread, so if you have anything UI-related in `subscribe`, then you have to add `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before it.

Comment: ok, thank you.  That is what I have though.  I have `.doOnSubscribe{ScreenState.Loading` . I then have ```.observeOn(mainThread)
            .subscribeOn(ioThread)``` . Can you tell me from my code above where I've gone wrong?

Comment: There can be one more case, specifically when you call UI logic in custom observables or use RxBinding framework which does that, then you need to add `.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`. This may be the case with your pull to refresh. Can you share some more code specifically about pull to refresh handling?

Comment: Sure so in my fragment I'm setting up a listener, when pulled I just call the `viewmodel.getBookList()` again .   ```private fun setUpSwipeToRefresh() {
        swipe_to_refresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            if (isNotRefreshing()) {
                viewModel.getBookList()
            }
        }
    }```

Comment: Did you try my original suggestion (add .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) after .observeScreenState())?